# Android - Usage of getSupportFragmentManager + RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, fragmentmanager

I have a an application that includes 5 bottom tabs. I use getSupportFragmentManager for fragment transaction. I had some custom fragment animation(left to right,right to left, bottom to top, top to bottom etc)

I use below implementation for transaction:

```
fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(activityContainerID, fragmentInstance); // for left-right animation
// fragmentTransaction.add => bottom to top
// fragmentTransaction.remove => top to bottom
fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

My each fragment has nested or non-nested recyclerview.

I press tab1 and update tab1.recyclerview data. When I press tab2 before onBindViewHolder ends, do it occurs a memory-leak error?

Sometimes, my app doesn't work as expected. `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't trigger `onCreateViewHolder` or `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `fragmentTransaction.replace()` which replace the current view to the  new view. That's why sometimes app doesn't work as expected.

Try this

```
private void changeFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    if (fragment == null)
        return;
    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = supportFragmentManager.getFragments();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentList.size(); i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragmentList.get(i));
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tag)) {
        Fragment oldFrag = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (oldFrag != null)
            transaction.show(oldFrag);
        else transaction.add(binding.frame.getId(), fragment, tag);
    } else transaction.add(binding.frame.getId(), fragment, tag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Should I use add/show/hide methods? What about 30-40+ fragments? I think this implementation causes OutOfMemory. Am I wrong?